# Any way to simplify this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, spectral-theory, standard-deviation

So I have a vector of asset allocation weights given by $x \in R^4$ and a covariance matrix of the asset returns $\Sigma \in R^{4,4}$. I know by the spectral theorem, $\Sigma = V DV^{-1}$ and the standard deviation of the returns is $\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}$. Is there any way to use this info and simplify the expression for the standard deviation and remove the square root?

Comment: Just a simple observation: Even if $\Sigma = I_4$, (identity matrix), the square root is needed, to compute the norm of $x$.